# ParallaxBackground doesn't work well with sprite scaled

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to set a ParallaxBackground for my AndEngine's game. So I did this:

```
    Sprite montagne = new Sprite(0, 0, RM.montagneBackground, vertex);
    Sprite piante = new Sprite(0, 0, RM.pianteBackground, vertex);
    montagne.setOffsetCenter(0, 0);
    montagne.setScaleCenterY(0);
    montagne.setScale(1.3f);
    piante.setScaleCenterY(0);
    piante.setOffsetCenter(0, 0);
    piante.setScale(1.3f);

    AutoParallaxBackground background = new AutoParallaxBackground(0.384f, 0.411f, 1f, 10f);
    background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(5, montagne));
    background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10, piante));
    scene.setBackground(background);
    scene.setBackgroundEnabled(true);
```

I scaled my two sprites (montagne, piante) by 1.3 f. If i run my application i can notice that when the sprites arrives at the end of the screen it disappears.. So I set the scale's values like this:

```
montagne.setScale(1f);
piante.setScale(1f);
```

And it works very well but the sprites are too small and i can't modify it with Photoshop because the sprites are both 1024 of width and It's the maximum I can store in my TextureAtlas...

So, how can I scale my sprites without having this problem ?

Comment: Questions don't need to be updated with [FIXED]. You accept the answer that worked for you, this tells people the issue is fixed.

Comment: Yes i know but i can't accept my OWN answer untill tomorrow so i have to write that !

Comment: Nope, you don't have to. Just wait until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with this:

```
montagne.setScaleCenter(0,0);
piante.setScaleCenter(0,0);
```

I think is due to the fact that when you scale a sprite you scale both side of it so when it runs, the ParallaxBackground make confusion thinking that the sprite passed the screen and so it's well to remove it.. With this method the sprite are scaled only in one side (the right and the top) and so you avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the offset or scale center. `AutoParallaxBackground` takes care of positioning the sprites with their scaled values:

```
public void onDraw(final GL10 pGL, final float pParallaxValue, final Camera pCamera) {
    pGL.glPushMatrix();
    {
        final float cameraWidth = pCamera.getWidth();
        final float shapeWidthScaled = this.mShape.getWidthScaled();
        float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor) % shapeWidthScaled;

        while(baseOffset > 0) {
            baseOffset -= shapeWidthScaled;
        }
        pGL.glTranslatef(baseOffset, 0, 0);
        float currentMaxX = baseOffset;

        do {
            this.mShape.onDraw(pGL, pCamera);
            pGL.glTranslatef(shapeWidthScaled, 0, 0);
            currentMaxX += shapeWidthScaled;
        } while(currentMaxX < cameraWidth);
    }
    pGL.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Relying primarily on the `getWidthScaled()` method:

```
@Override
public float getWidthScaled() {
       return this.getWidth() * this.mScaleX;
}
```

That means only the width and the scale are taken into account. Changing the offsets will affect how these are positioned, and apparently the parallax code doesn't take that into account.

Comment: Interesting. It seems like you'll need to do further debugging to try and see what's causing the issue. Make sure there's no gaps in your texture file and the texture is the same aspect ratio as you're specifying it when loading it. Finally, a "test" texture, that has values written on it indicating its size (think football field). As well as some test shapes to ensure you're not stretching the texture incorrectly or something similar.

Comment: It appears you deleted your comment. Does that mean it's working?

Comment: Yes it's working ! Watch my answer below ! :)